# Lodash merge including undefined values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use Lodash to merge object A into object B, but the trouble I am having is that object A has some undefined values and I want these to be copied over to object B.

Lodash docs for _.merge() says:

**"Recursively merges own enumerable properties of the source object(s), that don't resolve to undefined into the destination object."**

Is there another function that can do this, or can it be easily overwritten?

**EDIT A:**

Sample input:

```
A = {
  name: "Bob Smith",
  job: "Racing Driver",
  address: undefined
}

B = {
  name: "Bob Smith",
  job: "Web Developer",
  address: "1 Regent Street, London",
  phone: "0800 800 80"
}
```

Expected Output

```
B = {
  name: "Bob Smith",
  job: "Racing Driver",
  address: undefined,
  phone: "0800 800 80"
}
```

**EDIT B:**

Just to confirm, it needs to be a "deep" merge. object may contain nested objects.

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be to use 3rd package for this https://github.com/unclechu/node-deep-extend which goal is only deep merging and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

[`_.assign`/`_.extend`](http://lodash.com/docs#assign) will do that:

```
_.assign(B, A);
```

Comment: assign/extend don't do a "deep" merge do they?

Comment: No, I didn't think you needed that… You can either write your own method for that, or provide a callback to `extend` that recurses on objects and arrays.

Comment: Super thanks to Bergi for pointing this out. @jonhobbs I wrote a customizer for assignWith to do a deep merge here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455981/1828637 - i use this as i use it with react/redux.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bergi - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22581862/1828637 - `assign` will keep `undefined`. I did a customizer here using `assignWith` for deep merge with customizer, as i use this in redux/react:

```
function keepUnchangedRefsOnly(objValue, srcValue) {
    if (objValue === undefined) { // do i need this?
        return srcValue;
    } else if (isPlainObject(objValue)) {
        return assignWith({}, objValue, srcValue, keepUnchangedRefsOnly);
    } else if (Array.isArray(objValue)) {
        if (isEmpty(objValue) && !isEmpty(srcValue))return [...srcValue];
        else if (!isEmpty(objValue) && isEmpty(srcValue)) return objValue;
        else if (isEmpty(objValue) && isEmpty(srcValue)) return objValue; // both empty
        else return [ ...objValue, ...srcValue ];
    }
}
```

Usage like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437903/1828637

Answer (score 0):

I've met this issue like you. Just try replace `undefined` with `null` instead.

Example:

```js
const a = { something: 'has value' };
const b = { something: undefined };
const c = { something: null };

console.log(_.merge({}, a, b))
console.log(_.merge({}, a, c))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: null and undefined are not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here is a small function I use as a lodash replacement:

```
function merge(dst: any, src: any, stack = new Map<any, any>()) {
    if (dst === src || dst == null || src == null)
        return src
    
    if (stack.has(src))
        return stack.get(src)
    
    const dstTag = Object.prototype.toString.call(dst)
    const srcTag = Object.prototype.toString.call(src)
    if (dstTag !== srcTag || (dstTag !== '[object Object]' && dstTag !== '[object Array]'))
        return src

    stack.set(src, dst)
    Object.keys(src).forEach(key =>
        dst[key] = merge(dst[key], src[key], stack)
    )
    stack.delete(src)
    
    return dst
}
```

It fits my needs so far but, if you find anything wrong with it, tell me!

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](https://gist.github.com/kurtmilam/1868955) out. It is a small gist containing a `deep extend` lodash method which you can use within your own application. This will also allow you to get the functionality you need without adding another dependency in your app (since you're already using **lodash**)

Comment: That's for underscore.